# Understanding Parent - Child communication Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a component and then another component which is using it, and data is being parsed through to each other by means of a tab changing, what I am trying to do is when the page is left but the back button is pressed that the tab is remembered, to be able to do it I need to understand the data flow, the functions are identical so It's difficult to determine what is going on!

For instance, they are both using @Input and when I press a tab, both functions console if I add one in?

the component:

```
<div class="EngagementNavigationSecondary-Items" 

*ngIf="!selectedIndividual">
  <span
    *ngFor="let item of navList; let i = index"
    class="EngagementNavigationSecondary-Item"
    [ngClass]="{ 
      'EngagementNavigationSecondary-Item--Active': selectedItem === i,
      'EngagementNavigationSecondary-Item--One' : navList.length === 1,
      'EngagementNavigationSecondary-Item--Two' : navList.length === 2,
      'EngagementNavigationSecondary-Item--Three' : navList.length === 3
    }"
    (click)="clickTab(i)">
    {{ item.title | translate }}
  </span>
</div>
<div *ngIf="selectedIndividual">
  <span class="EngagementNavigationSecondary-Item" (click)="goBack()">
    <tl-icon
      size="18"
      name="chevron-left">
    </tl-icon>
    {{ 'Go back' | translate }}
  </span>
</div>
```

the logic:

```
export class EngagementNavigationSecondaryComponent implements OnInit {


 @HostBinding('class.EngagementNavigationSecondary') block = true;
  @Input() navList: EngagementNavigationItem[];
  @Input() selectedItem: number = 0;
  @Input() selectedIndividual: string;

  @Output() change: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter<number>();
  @Output() deselectIndividual: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  className: string;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.className = `EngagementNavigationSecondary-Item${this.navList.length}`;
  }

  goBack() {
    this.deselectIndividual.emit(true);
  }

  clickTab($event: number) {
    this.selectedItem = $event;
    this.change.emit($event);
  }
}
```

and now this component being used - within the side container component:

```
<tl-engagement-navigation-secondary
  *ngIf="navList"
  [navList]="navList"
  [selectedItem]="selectedTab"
  [selectedIndividual]="selectedIndividual"
  (change)="tabChange($event)"
  (deselectIndividual)="selectedIndividual = undefined">
</tl-engagement-navigation-secondary>
```

logic:

```
export class EngagementSideContainerComponent implements OnChanges, OnInit {
  @Input() focus: EngagementGraphNode;
  @Input() selectedTab: number;
  @Output() change: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter<number>();

  public navList: EngagementNavigationItem[];
  public selectedIndividual: EngagementUser;

  constructor(
    private urlService: UrlService,
    private router: Router,
    private mixPanelService: MixPanelService,
    private engagementService: EngagementService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.navList = this.getNavList();
  }

  tabChange(event) {
    this.change.emit(event);
  }
```

as you can see they are basically identical, so when I click on a tab, is the original component being called and then this is parsing data to the side container component? I think its important to understand so I can actually create the solution.

thanks if you can help!